# Hide spreader and add title for wheelnav

Tags: wheelnav.js

I'm trying to work with Wheelnav.js and right now attempting to add a centered title for my wheel instead of a spreader. I'm doing it all from javascript, without css at the moment.
I don't understand the purpose of spreaderPathInAttr and spreaderPathOutAttr:

```
wheel.spreaderPathInAttr = ...;
wheel.spreaderPathOutAttr = ...;
wheel.spreaderTitleInAttr = ...;
wheel.spreaderTitleOutAttr = ...;
```

The last two options is the font/text options for the spreader title to my understanding. Can I use the spreaderPathInAttr and spreaderPathOutAttr to hide the default circle around the title? Meaning I end up with only a text like 'Quit' etc. in the center of my wheel. Another thing regarding the spreader that I'm having difficulties with is the dots that appear whenever you close a menu. I would love to hide those as well. See attached pictures for references. Thanks.

[image: 3 dots for a wheel with 3 slices/items that is closed]

[image: Example of default circle/border appearing for spreaderTitle]

Forgot to add one thing. I'm working with multiple wheels by passing the parent wheel as input to any children object instantiated with `new wheelnaav(..);` and I did manage to hide the spreader circle previously using CSS, but it would only work for the first wheel, and not the rest. So my first wheel had the spreader hidden, but then the childrens spreader showed behind it.
The CSS I used for that was a simple assignment of a transparent non-color.

```
.wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-out, .wheelnav-piemenu-spreader-in {
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    stroke:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: I made a mistake by leaving in the enable css class on my wheel div.. This interfered with my settings being changed in javascript. So that's a mistake on my part .. I have now managed to remove the circle all together, so the text is the only thing left. However .. The 3 dots, one for each slice, is still being shown when the wheel is collapsed as seen on my images. Would love those removed, and perhaps anyone can point me towards a callback when the wheel is closed? If such a cb exists.

Comment: Currently, there is no such callback.

Comment: Okay, will figure it out without the callback.
- any way to remove the dots? one for each slice it seems

Comment: Can you create a JSBin or JSFiddle for further investigation?